# From Ubuntu 10.10, how do you connect to a Windows 7 share without a password setup?

Tags: ubuntu, windows, samba

I have:

1. Ubuntu 10.10
2. Windows 7 in virtual box (let's call this vbox)
3. Then another Windows 7 machine (let's call this remote) in the network

When I'm on vbox and browse (\ip.of.remote) I'm able to see the shared drives. No password was setup, and none was asked. When on Ubuntu, and I go to smb://ip.of.remote it asks for username/password.

How do I fix this?

Thanks!

UPDATE

- **Jan 30 2011**: I'm able to connect from Xubuntu to Windows (via Gigolo). It allows me to press connect even if there's no username. With Ubuntu though, if I remove the username, the connect button is grayed out. Maybe then it's just an interface problem?

Comment: Should this be migrated to http://askubuntu.com/?

Comment: Oh didn't know there was a stackexchange site particularly for Ubuntu. Thanks!

Comment: @kzh: Some of us don't understand why there's both, and feel that Ubuntu questions are perfectly welcome here as well...

Answer (score 1):

You can try providing `guest` as username and no password.

It seems to me that sometimes Ubuntu forgets to try with the guest credentials.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. :/ The authentication window just pops up again.